# Let's get critical: Aug 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sports Stack Exchange](http://sports.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: No longer relevant as the site is out of beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How do I read this chart about a FIFA World Cup Soccer/Futbol game from Google?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5032/how-do-i-read-this-chart-about-a-fifa-world-cup-soccer-futbol-game-from-google)

**Net Score: 11** (Excellent: 11, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does the penalty shoot out goal count as the person goal for a player?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5250/does-the-penalty-shoot-out-goal-count-as-the-person-goal-for-a-player)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [What guidelines would a World Cup official follow when deciding whether to book a player for hitting another when contesting a ball in the air?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4981/what-guidelines-would-a-world-cup-official-follow-when-deciding-whether-to-book)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Player throwing himself into another running player's way](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/player-throwing-himself-into-another-running-players-way)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is there a "hypernym" for "free base."](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/is-there-a-hypernym-for-free-base)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [In which countries did broadcasting rights for the World Cup sell for the most?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4976/in-which-countries-did-broadcasting-rights-for-the-world-cup-sell-for-the-most)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [In table tennis, why is a ball that hits the edge considered in?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5180/in-table-tennis-why-is-a-ball-that-hits-the-edge-considered-in)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What is the length of a cricket bail?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5122/what-is-the-length-of-a-cricket-bail)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 6)

---

- [Spectators involved in play](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5261/spectators-involved-in-play)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [What makes a cricket bowling action illegal?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4935/what-is-the-criteria-for-bowling-action-in-cricket)

**Net Score: -8** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 9)

---